# JQuery não executa corretamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou criando uma sidebar que irá conter umas opções de acessibilidade.
A grande que é, em partes a sidebar está funcionando corretamente.

1º Ao clicar no ícone da acessibilidade, a sidebar abre normalmente, se clicar novamente no ícone, ela fecha e se clicar mais uma vez, a sidebar abre, assim por diante... ok.

2º Dentro da sidebar foi adicionado um botão "X" para fechar a sidebar, o objetivo é ocultar o ícone da acessibilidade quando a sidebar estiver aberta e o usuário deverá fechar a sidebar com o "X". Ao clicar no ícone da acessibilidade, a sidebar abre, se o "X" for clicado, a sidebar fecha normalmente, mas se eu clicar novamente no ícone da acessibilidade para abrir a sidebar, ela não abre mais. Tentei entender o que poderia está acontecendo, mas não consegui, alguém tem ideia do que pode está ocorrendo?
Link para o exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/wmosquini/ko3ttLtp/19/

HTML:

```
<a class="abriracessibilidade" accesskey="0" title="Acessibilidade"><i class="uk-icon-wheelchair"></i></a>
<div class="menuacessibilidade">
    <div class="">
        <div class="uk-flex uk-flex-right">
            <a class="via-close">X</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#body" accesskey="1" title="Menu">Menu</a>
        <a href="#tm-top-b" accesskey="2" title="">Top b</a>
        <a href="#tm-top-c" accesskey="3" title="">Top c</a>
        <a href="#tm-top-d" accesskey="4" title="">Top d</a>
        <a href="#tm-main" accesskey="5" title="">Main</a>
        <a href="#tm-bottom-a" accesskey="6" title=""></a>
        <a href="#tm-bottom-b" accesskey="7" title=""></a>
        <a href="#tm-bottom-c" accesskey="8" title=""></a>
        <a href="#tm-bottom-d" accesskey="9" title=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuacessibilidade {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}
.menuacessibilidade.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.menuacessibilidade.close {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%)
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $('.abriracessibilidade').on('click', function () {
    $('.menuacessibilidade').toggleClass('open');
  });
});

$(function () {
  $('.via-close').on('click', function () {
    $('.menuacessibilidade').toggleClass('close');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
  $('.abriracessibilidade, .via-close').on('click', function () {
    $('.menuacessibilidade').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.menuacessibilidade {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}
.menuacessibilidade.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.menuacessibilidade.close {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.26.3/css/uikit.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a class="abriracessibilidade" accesskey="0" title="Acessibilidade"><i class="uk-icon-wheelchair"></i></a>
<div class="menuacessibilidade">
    <div class="">
        <div class="uk-flex uk-flex-right">
            <a class="via-close">X</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#body" accesskey="1" title="Menu">Menu</a>
        <a href="#tm-top-b" accesskey="2" title="">Top b</a>
        <a href="#tm-top-c" accesskey="3" title="">Top c</a>
        <a href="#tm-top-d" accesskey="4" title="">Top d</a>
        <a href="#tm-main" accesskey="5" title="">Main</a>
        <a href="#tm-bottom-a" accesskey="6" title=""></a>
        <a href="#tm-bottom-b" accesskey="7" title=""></a>
        <a href="#tm-bottom-c" accesskey="8" title=""></a>
        <a href="#tm-bottom-d" accesskey="9" title=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

A questão está no `ToogleClass`, quando você coloca `close`.
Tenta usar dessa forma

Comment: Muito obrigado Rafael, funcionou perfeitamente!!

Answer (score 1):

Faltou você remover a classe `close` antes de dar um `toggleClass("open")`, também faltou remover a classe `open` ao dar um `toggleClass("close")`.

Seu código deve ficar da seguinte forma:

```
$(function () {
  $('.abriracessibilidade').on('click', function () {
    $('.menuacessibilidade').removeClass("close").toggleClass('open');
  });

    $('.via-close').on('click', function () {
    $('.menuacessibilidade').removeClass("open").toggleClass('close');
  });
});
```

Comment: Boa Diego, sua solução também funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Apenas faça isso em seu *script*, não precisa tudo isso de código para executar a mesma função.

```
$('.abriracessibilidade, .via-close').on('click', function () {
    $('.menuacessibilidade').toggleClass('open');
});
```

> **Entendendo o problema**

Ao clicar no *Icone* ele aplica o estilo *open*, se clicar novamente ele remove o estilo.

```
$(function () {
  $('.abriracessibilidade').on('click', function () {
    $('.menuacessibilidade').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

Aqui ele vai a mesma coisa que o primeiro, só que em vez de remover o estilo *open* ele aplica o *close*, ai aonde gera o problema, pois o estilo *open* ainda esta aplicado.

```
$(function () {
  $('.via-close').on('click', function () {
    $('.menuacessibilidade').toggleClass('close');
  });
});
```